# calculation of $x$ in $x^{2}= 2^{-x}$

Tags: calculus

Total no. of real solution of the equation $x^2 = 2^{-x}$

My Try:: Let $f(x) = x^2-2^{-x}$

Diff. both side w.r.to $x\;,$ we get

$f^\prime(x) = 2x+2^{-x}\ln(2)$

$f^{\prime\prime}(x)=2+2^x.\ln(2)>0 \; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

Here $f^{\prime\prime}(x)>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

So $f(x)$ is an Concave upward function that means if function $f(x)$ has real roots then it must be $2$

But using wolframalpha We get $3$ real solution.

So were is my mistake

Thanks

Comment: As I told you on your previous question: you're supposed to accept your favorite answers, if they're satisfactory. You've accepted $0$ answers on $13$ questions so far.

Comment: Oh Sorry Git Gud

Comment: Don't apologize to me. Go to your profile and accept answers for your previous questions.

Comment: How can i accept answer  would you like to explain me .i was thinking that votes means accepting answer.

Comment: No. When you over your mousse below the downvote arrow, a 'check' sign will appear. You should click on it to accept an answer. If you do this properly, the check sign will be visible permanently and it will turn green.

Comment: @juantheron: you can upvote each answer, but you can accept only one (but you can change your mind if another appears better). Upvotes and downvotes lock in after a few minutes (but can be changed if a post is edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is using the Lambert-W function.

Since $x^2=2^{-x}\Rightarrow \log(2)x/2\,e^{\log(2)x/2}=\pm\log(2)/2$, we get that
$$
x=\frac2{\log(2)}\mathrm{W}\left(\pm\frac{\log(2)}{2}\right)
$$
where $\mathrm{W}$ is the [Lambert-W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

For positive arguments, $\mathrm{W}$ only has one real branch, so the only positive real root of the equation is `N[2/Log[2] LambertW[0, Log[2]/2], 20]`:
$$
x\doteq0.76666469596212309311
$$
For negative arguments, $\mathrm{W}$ has two real branches. The negative real solutions are `N[2/Log[2] LambertW[0, -Log[2]/2], 20]`
$$
x=-2
$$
and `N[2/Log[2] LambertW[-1, -Log[2]/2], 20]`
$$
x=-4
$$

Answer (score 2):

Because
$$
f''(x)=2-2^{-x}\ln^2 2
$$
and it is not always positive. You need differentiate one more time to see that $f'''>0$ and conclude that $f$ have at most three solutions

Comment: Thanks Norbert. $f''(x)=2-2^{-x}\ln^2(2)$ and $f'''(x)=2^{-x}\ln^2(3)>0$ means $f'(x)$ is Concave upward function So It has at most $2$ solution.So how can i prove that $f(x)$ has at most $3$ solution.

Comment: Suppose $f$ has four roots or more. Take a set of four consecutive roots in increasing order $\{a,b,c,d\}$. What does Rolle tell you about $f(a)$ & $f(b)$? What about $f(b)$ & $f(c)$? And finally, what about $f(c)$ & $f(d)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^2-2^{-x}$, then $f''(x)=2-(\log2)^22^{-x}$. Since $f''$ is increasing from $f''(-\infty)=-\infty$ to $f''(+\infty)=+\infty$, $f'$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,x]$ and increasing on $[x,+\infty)$, for some $x$. Two cases can occur.

- Either $f'(x)\geqslant0$, then $f'$ is nonnegative everywhere and $f$ is increasing. Since $f(-\infty)=-\infty$ and $f(+\infty)=+\infty$, this implies that $f=0$ has exactly one root.
- Or $f'(x)\lt0$, then $f'$ is positive then negative then positive.

Since $f(-3)\gt0$ and $f(0)\lt0$, the second case occurs. Thus, the function $f$ is negative then positive then negative then positive, and it has exactly three zeroes, one in each interval $(-\infty,-3)$, $(-3,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$. The zeroes in the first two intervals are easy-to-guess integers, and the positive zero happens to lie in the interval $(\frac12,1)$ since $f(\frac12)\lt0\lt f(1)$.